# Убрать окно подтверждения ответа на собственный вопрос для высокореповых участников

Tags: предложение, самоответы

Когда отвечаешь на свой же вопрос, но делаешь это не сразу, а по прошествии некоторого времени, то появляется окно, требующее подтверждения:

> [image: Подтверждение ответа на собственный вопрос]

Оно безусловно полезное для новичков, но кажется несколько излишним для участников с большим стажем. Предлагаю его убрать при достижении определённого уровня репутации, допустим, 1000 реп.